# 500 - Internal server error for SQL Server error

Tags: coldfusion

I have a new VPS account, whereas before I've always been running my sites on a shared server.

I have "Enable Robust Exception Information" checked, and "Enable Request Debugging Output" checked.

I'm getting a 500 - Internal server error, which isn't very helpful.

And I can see in the application.log the following error:

> Error Executing Database Query.[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC
>   Driver][SQLServer]The column name 'AttachmentDesc' is specified more
>   than once in the SET clause.

So I see the error, but it would be better if the page displayed the error rather than me having to find it in the application.log.

Q: Is there another setting that I'm missing to help display errors on the page itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like IIS is hiding the errors from you. Under 'Error Pages' in IIS, select the 500 error and click 'Edit feature settings' and select 'Detailed errors' - you should now see the full error info (provided debugging is on n CF).

Comment: Yes, depending on your settings, IIS can show 'friendly' error pages instead of detailed errors. It does not 'mask' the status code (i.e. it still returns 500 code), but does hide the error info, which can make debugging rather hard in development.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable debugging by going into ColdFusion administrator and enabling the "Enable Robust Exception Information" option.  In CF10, you can find this option under the "Debugging & Logging" section in "Debug Output Settings."

Here is the link for CF 8 http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Debug_02.html and for CF 9 http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html.

Answer (score 2):

IIS may be hiding the errors from you (see azawaza's answer).  You can stop this at ColdFusion layer, by disabling the ColdFusion Administrator -> Settings -> "Enable HTTP status codes".  Then even the error pages will give code 200 for success, and IIS won't replace the output.

Comment: Thanks krubo.  I think @azawaza's answer solved it.  I just forgot to tag it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (500 error instead of detailed debugging) but on shared hosting. Setting

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

in **web.config** did the job.