# Retrieving error message from http.get request

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, express, error-handling

I am using Express.js and msnodesqlv8 to run statement.

The error caught has the right elements to be bubbled up to the controller, but does not propagate there properly for the **Error** part.

The error returned is as follows:

> { **Error**: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The
>   INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "MyConstraint". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Mydatabase", table "dbo.MyTable".
>   sqlstate: '23000', code: 547 }

But the error returned to the controller with the status code 500 is not consumed properly and *I am only able to access the sqlstate and code*. Is this because the error message from SQL Server is not formatted correctly to be parsed?

How to retreive the **Error** part of the message?

```
var sql = require('msnodesqlv8');

app.get('/myroute/*', function (req, res) {

var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
var param1= queryData.param1;

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowOriginUrl)
let txtFile =  "myFile.sql"

let query = fs.readFileSync(txtFile,'utf8');
query = query.replace('?param1',param1) 

sql.query(regroupement_conn, query, (err, rows) => {
    if(err)
    {
        //throw err;
        console.log(err)
        result = res.status(500).send({
             message : err
          })
    }
    else
    {
        result = res.send(rows);
    }
});
```

})

I am consuming the error like so from my controller

```
return  this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/myroute/` ,{params}).pipe(

catchError((err) => {
    throw  err;
})
)
```

Comment: Check out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426984/500-internal-server-error-for-sql-server-error

Comment: How is this applicable to express.js?